# UITextfield Text is Invisible

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextfield

I have some textfilds programmatically created and added to `UIScrollview`. First the textfields show text when edited but if you go to another `ViewController` then pop back the text is invisible . It(text) is invisible but it has not gone. This issue happens only on iPad. On the simulator it works perfectly. Why is this happening?

Comment: How do you know it's "invisible but not gone"? Is the text field itself on screen (give it a background color to be sure)?

Comment: I know it's invisible and not gone because in my process i submit those content and save them in a distant databse , i find them on the database but they are invisible in the app

Comment: And how about the text field? Do you know that it is still on screen, and not off to the side somewhere?

Comment: Yes it is still on the screen i can see and edited , but the previous content wil be deleted if i edit one of them

Comment: Maybe it would help you understant , the textfields  have their placeholders